# How can I do opposite key for join or reverse the opposite output

Tags: mysql

How to use Join in SQL to get Not Common

This is my table A

```
   +------+----------+
   | id   | contact  |
   +------+----------+
   | 4    | 1111-111 |
   | 5    | 2222-222 |
   | 6    | 3333-333 |
   | 7    | 4444-444 |
   | 8    | 5555-555 |
   +------+----------+
```

This is my table B

```
   +------+----------+
   | id   |   Name   |
   +------+----------+
   | 1    | Juan     |
   | 2    | Carlo    |
   | 3    | Mark     |
   | 4    | Joseph   |
   | 5    | May      |
   +------+----------+
```

this is my query = > Select name from B inner join A where B.id = A.id

```
   +----------+
   |   Name   |
   +----------+
   | Joseph   |
   | May      |
   +----------+
```

But my expected output should be this:

```
   +----------+
   |   Name   |
   +----------+
   | Juan     |
   | Carlo    |
   | Mark     |
   +----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `left join`

```
Select name 
from B 
left join A ON B.id = A.id
where A.id is null
```

See [this explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)